# Jenkins builds failing with a missing file error even though the file is there

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, build, continuous-integration

I have a Jenkins server running and have a couple of builds that are all working.  However, this morning when I tried to add another one it kept failing with the error -

`[test.gov] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7055290339554583413.sh
+ ./opt/jenkins/build.sh
/tmp/hudson7055290339554583413.sh: line 2: /opt/jenkins/build.sh: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`

The shell script is at that path and has that name.  If I make it ./opt/jenkins/build.sh it still fails with the same error.  The command I have in the "Execute Shell" section in the "Command" text box is `/opt/jenkins/build.sh`.  I tried `./opt/jenkins/build.sh` as well.

The script is on a CentOS system btw.

This is the script I am trying to run -

```
echo "git pull"
cd /var/www/path/for/my_website/docroot/
git checkout master
git pull


echo "change ownership to apache"
chown -R apache:apache *
echo "running drush commands"
drush updb -y
#drush fra -y
drush cc all
```

Comment: Did you find an actual solution to this problem?  I am facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes for your path in the shell command, a "." may not work.  Instead, use the macro expression to get the workspace.

So for example: %WORKSPACE%/opt/jenkins/usda_gov_build.sh

This will give the shell command the exact path of the file in your jobs workspace.

Comment: Is your Jenkins server Linux or Windows? Typically I have only seen this when someone has tried to run a linux command on a windows server.

Comment: Linux.  CentOS I believe.  If it is helpful, the other jobs in the server have `/opt/jenkins/deploy/bin/build2.sh` in the command text area, even though the path to get to their shell scripts is `/opt/jenkins/deploy/bin/build2.sh`.

Comment: The next thing I would verify is the file is in the path you are expecting by checking the builds workspace after it runs. Sometimes I have seen the path different than I was expecting other times I have seen source control not pull in the file I was expecting

Comment: What exactly is the workspace for Jenkins?  The /opt/Jenkins folder?  Sorry, new to Linux so im not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: Np! It depends on your configuration. You can set the first line of your shell script to ..... echo %WORKSPACE% .....and that should print it out for you.

Comment: It just prints it.  `+ echo %WORKSPACE%
%WORKSPACE%
+/opt/jenkins/deploy/bin/usda_gov_build.sh
/tmp/hudson4730645853517949633.sh: line 3: /opt/jenkins/deploy/bin/usda_gov_build.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Looking at the build step, it fails before it can even assign a workspace since it cannot find the right file specified.

Comment: It gives me an output now. `$ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1866298419092566890.sh
+ echo /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testDirectory
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testDirectory
+ cd /opt/jenkins/deploy/bin/build.sh`

Comment: Okay so now you can use that path to very your files exist on the system or you could use the UI and look through the workspace there as well.

Comment: Im pretty sure that is the file path that Jenkins creates temporarily when it runs, because that path doesn't exist on my system otherwise

Comment: Interesting.  When I run ls -lah inside of the build window, the outputs that it gives me indicates that it cant see any shell scripts for some reason.  Like if I am inside of the /opt/jenkins folder, I have aboutt 6 shell scripts there, but when it does ls -lah it does not see any of them for some reason.  Do you know why this would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Often the "build.sh: No such file or directory" error actually means that the [shebang](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang) line within `build.sh` does not point to an executable file. Check the contents of build.sh to make sure that path exists.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there is no shebang line inside of my shell script.  All I want the script to do is go into the docroot of the Drupal website, and do a git checkout/pull.  I edited my original question and added my script there, so if you see something wrong please let me know.

Comment: Interesting.  When I run `ls -lah` inside of the build window, the outputs that it gives me indicates that it cant see any shell scripts for some reason.  Like if I am inside of the /opt/jenkins folder, I have aboutt 6 shell scripts there, but when it does ls -lah it does not see any of them for some reason.  Do you know why this would be the case?